# How to insert datetime into mysql from mssql with INSERT INTO OPENQUERY SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, datetime, timestamp

I've been using the following format to insert into my mysql database previously, and would like to keep it uniform.

```
INSERT INTO     OPENQUERY (ENET, 'SELECT * FROM ActiveDirectory.Computers')  -- MYSQL database
SELECT          c.[CommonName],
                c.[DistinguishedName],
                c.[SAMAccountName],
                c.[DNSHostName],
                c.[Location],
                c.[Division],
                c.[Department],
                c.[ManagedBy],
                c.[MachineRole],
                CAST(CAST(c.[LastLogon] as timestamp) as datetime) AS LastLogon,
                c.[OperatingSystem],
                c.[OperatingSystemVersion],
                c.[ServicePack],
                c.[OU],
                c.[CreatedOn],
                c.[ChangedOn],
                CASE WHEN c.[UserAccountControl] & 2 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [Enabled]     -- Check to see if disabled.  Disabled = bitwise of 2;  4098 = 4096 + 2 = Trust Account + Disabled
FROM            [IT_ActiveDirectory].[dbo].[ADComputerTable] c -- MSSQL database
```

My problem comes when inserting the fields that are datetimes in MSSQL (`c.LastLogon, c.CreatedOn, c.ChangedOn`) into mysql fields that are also datetimes.  I have tried almost every combination of `CAST()` and `CONVERT()` I can think of, but I may have missed something.  I have also tried changing mysql's field type to timestamp.

It returns: `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

It seems strange to me that MSSQL won't just send the data to MYSQL and let it do the conversion.  Instead it looks like it is trying to convert and match the datatypes and data before it sends it to MYSQL.

If I can't  insert it this way, I am open to another format, like if its possible to do the insert inside of the `OPENQUERY() SELECT`.  Any suggestions?  I'm dead in the water at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to convert to ISO-8601 format string:

```
INSERT INTO OPENQUERY (ENET, 'SELECT * FROM ActiveDirectory.Computers')
SELECT
    ...,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, LastLogon, 126) AS LastLogon

FROM [IT_ActiveDirectory].[dbo].[ADComputerTable];
```

Also I don't like `SELECT *` in `OPENQUERY`. If columns are matched by position it is error-prone. Consider expanding start to columns.